# Adding label at runtime in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox, runtime, label

I am creating a custom textbox control in asp.net. I am placing some in-built validation in the textbox for alphabetic, numeric, email addresses. Now I want if any of these validations fail a label (an error label) should be added dynamically below the textbox.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a label, but a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) (or one of the other validators).

Set its `Display` property to dynamic if you want it to appear only when an error is detected.

Comment: hmmm... Thanks Steve but I want to add label here because I am not using any validator control. Actually I am trying to create a custom textbox control where you can specify the type of validation in enum and it will show the error in label below the textbox if any validation is failed.

Comment: Why don't you create a separate control, inheriting `BaseValidator` and dedicated to your custom control? You will benefits the whole validation framework, including the ability to use a ValidationSummary, the ability to put the error message anywhere in the page, the possibility to use Page.Validate, the validation groups, etc.

Comment: Are you saying that I should define a class inheriting BaseValidator that will have all the validations and use it's object in custom textbox control  ?

Comment: Basically, the custom textbox should not be aware of any validator. The validator is responsible for the validation process, and can read the custom textbox's public properties if required. Take a look at the CompareValidator. it own several properties that can setup the validation as needed (operator, type of data, etc.). You can reproduce the same behavior with your own attributes and rules.

Comment: Sounds like I am getting it. Thanks for guiding me Steve.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a separate label, each `Validator` in ASP.NET can be given an appropriate `ErrorMessage` which can appear next to the textbox.

Have a [look at the list of validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.aspx) that are inherited from the `BaseValidator`, which will give you everything you need to do this

If you are insistent that you want to use your own validation, and are doing it using client-side JavaScript, then create something like the following...

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblErrors" style="display:none;">
  You have errors!
</asp:Label>
```

Then in your validator...

```
document.getElementById("<%=lblErrors.ClientID%>").style.display = 
  (anyErrors ? "" : "none");
```

If your validation is all done on the server, then have something like...

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblErrors" Visible="false">
  You have errors!
</asp:Label>
```

Then in your validator...

```
lblErrors.Visible = anyErrors
```

(You would also want to make sure that `lblErrors.Visible` is also set to `false` if the validation is not taking place)

Answer (score 0):

Might also ValidationSummary control can be useful for you.

[ValidationSummary on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)